# How to restrict access to a particular folder in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I have a subdirectory in my root folder by the name files. I want to deny direct access to files under this directory. However my application can read and write to this directory programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible try to locate the files under the `App_Data` folder, which is intended as a store for data files that are used by the web application but not served directly to the users.

Answer (score 1):

in `web.config`, you can set up authorisation on the sub-directory

```
   <location path="name of subdirectory">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

As [Fredrik points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265526/how-to-restict-access-to-a-paricular-folder-in-asp-net/1265529#1265529), the `App_Data` folder may be a better place to put these files. What type of files are they?

Comment: I have a bin folder not App_Data. I have used it and got the result i was waiting for.

Comment: you can add an APP_DATA folder by right-clicking the project > ADD > Add ASP.NET folder > APP_DATA

Comment: This article may be of use to you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add to your web.config section

```
   <location path="YourPath">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment guys. The web.config trick not working for me.
I have used bin folder and it is giving satisfactory result.

Comment: you need to ensure that the path to the location in web.config is correct.